# How to use map function to check the property in json is missing and return 0

Tags: underscore.js

I want to group by name and sum the core_mt***value fields if present or add 0 to the sum for that field

```
var result = [{ "core_year": "2015", "core_mtdaugvalue": "640", "core_mtdaugqty_decimal": "40", "name": "PRECEPT EC150 1X20L DRM AU", "defaultuomid": { "entityName": "uom", "id": "a566917b-c659-e411-8b5b-0050568902b7", "isNew": false, "primaryName": "L" } }, { "core_year": "2015", "core_mtdaugvalue": "3780", "core_mtdsepvalue": "1260", "core_mtdaugqty_decimal": "120", "core_mtdsepqty_decimal": "40", "name": "VELOCITY EC347,2 1X20L DRM AU", "defaultuomid": { "entityName": "uom", "id": "a566917b-c659-e411-8b5b-0050568902b7", "isNew": false, "primaryName": "L" } }];

var finalResult = _.chain(result)
                        .groupBy("name")
                        .map(function (value, key) {
                            return {
                                brandname: key,
                                Value: _.map(function (value) {

                                    var sum = 0;

                                    if (value[0].core_mtdjanvalue == undefined)
                                        sum = sum + 0;
                                    else
                                        sum = sum + value[0].core_mtdjanvalue;

                                    return { Value: sum };
                                })
                            }
                        })
                       .value();
```

I tried above code, but it returns null as below

```
[{"brandname":"PRECEPT EC150 1X20L DRM AU","Value":[null]},{"brandname":"VELOCITY EC347,2 1X20L DRM AU","Value":[null]}]
```

Can anyone tell where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no collection passed to the map function.

Comment: Above map function value parameter is passed to second map function.

Comment: It should be something like `_.map(value, function(thingy) {...})`

Comment: I have found another alternate, made use of JS function as below var finalResult = _.chain(result)
                        .groupBy("name")
                        .map(function (value, key) {
                            return {
                                brandname: key,
                                Value: GroupValue(Value)
                                })
                            }
                        })
                       .value();

Comment: @GruffBunny He is using chain. http://underscorejs.org/#chain. The collection is `result` and it is being passed to `_.chain(result)`. Just thought I'd let you now.

Comment: @John - it's the second map that's the problem - the one in the chain is ok

Comment: @GruffBunny true didn't see that.

Comment: Please add the output you expect.